# Nextcloud sync status column in any file browser

Tags: nautilus, dolphin, thunar, nemo, nextcloud

Is there a way to get a sync status column of Nextcloud in any of the common file browser like Nemo, Thunar, Dolphin etc. like it is shown in Windows?

[image]

Comment: Theoretically it should have at least a sync emblem as Dropbox do. All mentioned file managers [are supported](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nextcloud&searchon=all) by Ubuntu packages. You can start by installing relevant package for your current file-manager for your desktop and check it.

Answer (score 1):

For Nautilus ("File" app), simply run this command and then reboot :

```
sudo apt install nautilus-nextcloud
```

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKlVS.png)